# Testing private methods in pytest

Tags: python, automated-tests, pytest

I have class `OctoApi`. It has two private methods `__headers_generate` and `__data_generate`. I get it in tests through fixture

```
@pytest.fixture()
def api():
    return octo.api.OctoApi(AUTH_TOKEN)
```

How do I create tests for these methods?

Comment: You don't, or at least not directly. Test things through their public API.

Comment: @jonrsharpe So I can't test if the private methods work correctly?

Comment: There are no private methods in Python.

Comment: What makes you say that? You test that _the class_ works correctly, which either means 1. the private methods do too; or 2. the private methods are unreachable and can be deleted.

Comment: @KlausD. in the sense that "we're all consenting adults" there's nothing you can't actually get access to, but from a design and encapsulation perspective the tests should follow the intent of `_private_by_convention` or `__name_mangled` identifiers.

Comment: @jonrsharpe. I new in testing. It literally is my first testing practice) So I thought I needed to check if the headers were generated correctly and, separately, if the methods that use those headers work correctly. Thank you for your reply. I realized that I only need to test the public interface

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm totally aware of that. But calling the methods "public" or "private" without further explanation is extremely misleading to Python newcomers especially if they come from languages that have these qualifiers.